# Issues updating moq creating mock dbSet with T objects function from Entity Framework (on .NET) to Entity Framework Core (on .NET 6)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, moq

I'm working on upgrading testing project from .NET Framework to .NET 6 that utilizes Moq.

I have the following function that is used to create a Mock of a DbSet object by using the provided set of objects.

```
public static Mock<DbSet<T>> CreateMockDbSetWithObjects<T>(IEnumerable<T> mockObjects) where T : class, new()
{
    var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
    mockDbSet.Setup(m => m.Local).Returns(new ObservableCollection<T>(mockObjects));

    IQueryable<T> mockComponentsAsQueryable = mockObjects.AsQueryable();
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(mockComponentsAsQueryable.Provider);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(mockComponentsAsQueryable.Expression);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(mockComponentsAsQueryable.ElementType);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(mockComponentsAsQueryable.GetEnumerator());
    mockDbSet.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Returns(new T());

    return mockDbSet;
}
```

I'm having difficulties trying to understand how to upgrade the couple of lines that are throwing errors (in new .NET 6 EF Core test project) - line 4 with the first `.Setup` throws this error:

> CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.LocalView'

I attempted the following update

```
mockDbSet.Setup(m => m.Local).Returns(new LocalView<T>(mockObjects));
```

However, the above now throws another error

> CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet'

I also get this error

> CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry'

It seems like the behavior in mocking in EF Core is drastically different from EF. I saw someone put "EF Core allows you to use an in-memory provider for testing." How would I do so when passing the objects that I want to add in-memory?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Al

Comment: You can use the "in-memory" provider, but this is not a full relational provider. So there are cases where your unit tests pass, but errors are thrown in real world code.  I'd use an in memory Sqlite db, even though this is technically not a unit test (SQLite is an external dependency).  I'e used it with great success on a number of projects.  Also mocking all the functionality of DBContext and DBSet is difficult if not impossible.  See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/choosing-a-testing-strategy?source=recommendations)